# Securing JWT tokens in a AJAX call

Tags: security, jwt

Say site A has a piece of javascript that does an ajax call to an endpoint on site B. Site A uses a JWT generated from site B to authenticate the requests.

Wouldn't a user be able to get the JWT, simply by inspecting (e.g Chrome) the request and it's headers? Then he could use that JWT and make his own requests.

If so, how should one use the JWT when doing ajax calls in the browser, without having it in plain text in the javascript file?

e.g

```js
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  beforeSend: function (request)
  {
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2p3dC1pZHAuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJtYWlsdG86bWlrZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTQzNDk0NDIwMywiZXhwIjoxNDM0OTQ3ODAzLCJpYXQiOjE0MzQ5NDQyMDMsImp0aSI6ImlkMTIzNDU2IiwidHlwIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9yZWdpc3RlciJ9.UPFXFOgvmXUenz4mtJkzSEiBc_k6hdytTbxIrDDET2o");
  },
  url: "https://siteb.com/api/articles/",
  success: function(data) {
    // do something with data
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, user may access JWT token on his browser - this is no different as with cookies.

For the scenarios where **user of B** authorizes your application A to access the B **on his behalf**, there is no need to protect JWT token from the user himself - just from the 3rd parties.

If you imagine a scenario where service B somehow authorizes your application A to access it, then JWT tokens should never ever go to the browser but stay on the server side of A. Your AJAX calls then should go to A which communicates to B using proper JWT.